# How to describe "punishing" some text by making it less visible?

Tags: word-choice

For example, downvoted answers on StackExchange.

More-or-less normal variant seems to be "to gray out", but it's seems limited to gray colour (not to small font, pictures, strike-through or other methods of making the text visibly less important)...

**Answers I like so far:** (in short)

- obscure
- fade/bleach/blanch/gray out/strike though (i.e. the specific effect)
- [be]dim
- deemphasize
- mute
- demote

Comment: It's not the text that's being punished. It's the person who posted it.

Comment: I mean the text effect itself. "punishing" here means "marking for everyone that there is a problem here" (edit the title if there's better word).

Comment: Perhaps blanched, bleached, faded, washed out?  I doubt a standard word has arisen to denote grayed-out text.

Comment: How about *"demoted text"*?

Comment: I would use "fade" (suggested by @jwpat7).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about "obscure"? "v. To make dim or indistinct", "Not capable of being clearly seen, on account of deficient illumination." (Reference: Wordnik.)

Comment: I think the common usage for obscure implies a 'thing' that does the obscuring.  The question is about the online practice of making something less-visible to other users i.e. by greying its color.

Comment: One problem with _obscure_ is that it can also mean _to make more confusing or difficult to understand_, which may be an unfortunate second meaning when applied to text.

Answer (score 5):

The commonly used word is

> moderate

Which carries a contextual meaning to depreciate the item in question relative to its peers/etc.  The frame of your question is about "punishing" a conversational contribution - and such "punishment" requires authoritative privileges.  These privileges *define* the role of the Moderator in a conversation.

However, 'to moderate' is not a universal 'downvote,' as moderating can raise the level of attention.  Regardless, the common expression for downvoting (and similar) is to *moderate*.

A commonly related concept is

> muting

as in, [conversation muting](https://www.google.com/search?q=converstion+muting).  "Masking" is also used in a similar way.

Where these are words that, in their native contexts (audio, print/art, painting), have an all-or-nothing meaning (e.g. "mute" means "off") – in the context of web media and conversational streams, the words can be used with many shades of meaning.  This position is nouveau, and you probably won't find it in a dictionary of any sort (besides [EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/)!)

As most are alluding to, the more common figure of speech is given for the emphasizing / highlighting focus of top-ranked elements.

Comment: (Intended to accept this answer also, but can't make the question Community Wiki to do this...)

Comment: @Vi0 I appreciate the thought.

Answer (score 4):

Reduce font size, dim, grey out, camouflage (or blend), strike through, increase transparency...

Generically speaking, I would say these are all ways to *deemphasize* text, or to make text *less prominent*.

> **prominent**: easy to see or notice; conspicuous

Comment: If I understand what the O.P. is asking for, this wouldn't be restricted to something negative. For example, in a computer-based training module, links to already-completed components might be dimmed, or greyed out, or reduced in size - that is, the text would be modified so that it was less prominent than the other text surrounding it.

Comment: Originally I thought about "something negative" (I just saw an _____-ed answer and took interest "how to call it?"), but the general question is about "make visibly less important".

Answer (score 2):

- penalize (when down-voted)
- obscure
- conceal
- hide (elementary but works surprisingly well)
- bedim (fits with graying-out)
- block
- flag (technical, usually for reporting abuse or attracting moderator attention)

Comment: What about just *dim*?

Comment: @TimLymington, don't really know about that. Example usage: "Your post was dimmed"? IMO, it sounds weird. Bedim means making something dim whereas dim just means losing brightness or in this case, visibility.

Comment: When I use a dimmer switch, I myself dim the light. Different places, different usages I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

The usual action is to *[strike](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/strike#strike_54)* the text:

> **strike**, *tr.v.*
>
> **10**. to remove words from a document, for example by drawing a line through them

If you simply want to *mark* the text as "bad," you can use one of a number of [proofreading marks](http://wadsworth.com/english_d/templates/student_resources/1413001890_burnett/UsageHandbook/edit_marks.htm).

Comment: "Strike" or "gray out" is one of particular methods. I'm looking for a general term "do something with the text to mark it bad".

Comment: In that case, I'd be surprised if there's a specific word. I think you'd have to say "display the text differently to show that it is bad" or something like that.

Comment: Then _mark_ is the general term. See my expanded answer.

Answer (score 0):

disparage

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/disparage

Actually, Dictionary.com hits my intended sense of the word better for this use:

dis·par·age/diˈsparij/
Verb:
Regard or **represent** as being of little worth.
Synonyms:
depreciate - belittle - decry - underestimate

Answer (score -1):

**Severed**

in the sense of cut off (say from a discussion).

Or **Muted**

in the sense that nobody wants to hear what is being said in this post, so we pressed the 'mute' button.

Or **Obliterated**: Destroyed

Or **Effaced**: Erased